# traverse json using options parent id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
    [
      {
        "id": "name",
        "model": "name",
        "name": "name",
        "label": "Name",
        "placeholder": "Enter your name",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "text",
        "options": [],
        "objectType":"parent",
        "parentId": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "existingcustomer",
        "name": "ExistingCustomer",
        "label": "Exisiting Customer",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "radio",
        "objectType":"parent",
        "options": [
          {"label": "Yes", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue": "no","id": "existingcustomer_yes","objectType": "parent"},
          {"label": "No", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue":"yes","id": "existingcustomer_no","objectType": "parent"}
        ],
        "parentId": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "existingcustomername",
        "name": "existingcustomername",
        "label": "Hello Existing Customer Please Enter Your Name",
        "placeholder": "Enter You Name",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "text",
        "objectType": "child",
        "options": [],
        "parentId": "existingcustomer_yes"
      },
      {
        "id": "selectpackage",
        "name": "selectpackage",
        "label": "Hello Existing Customer, Select Your Package Please",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "select",
        "objectType": "parent",
        "options": [
          {"label": "Package 1", "name": "select_package","optionValue": "Package 1","id": "selectpackage_package1", "objectType": "parent"},
          {"label": "Package 2", "name": "select_package","optionValue":"Package 2","id": "selectpackage_package2", "objectType": "parent"}
        ],
        "parentId": "existingcustomer_yes"
      },
      {
        "id": "selectpackage1",
        "name": "selectpackage1",
        "label": "Hello Existing Customer, Select Your Package 1 Details",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "select",
        "objectType": "child",
        "options": [
          {"label": "Package 1.1", "name": "select_package","optionValue": "Package 1","id": "selectpackage1_package11","objectType": "child"},
          {"label": "Package 1.2", "name": "select_package","optionValue":"Package 2","id": "selectpackage1_package12","objectType": "child"}
        ],
        "parentId": "selectpackage_package1"
      },
      {
        "id": "selectpackage2",
        "name": "selectpackage2",
        "label": "Hello Existing Customer, Select Your Package 2 Details",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "select",
        "objectType": "child",
        "options": [
          {"label": "Package 2.1", "name": "select_package","optionValue": "Package 1","id": "selectpackage2_package21",  "objectType": "child"},
          {"label": "Package 2.2", "name": "select_package","optionValue":"Package 2","id": "selectpackage2_package22",  "objectType": "child"}
        ],
        "parentId": "selectpackage_package2"
      },
      {
        "model": "newcustomername",
        "name": "newcustomername",
        "label": "Hello New Customer Please Enter Your Name",
        "placeholder": "Enter You Name",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "text",
        "objectType": "child",
        "options": [],
        "parentId": "existingcustomer_no"
      }
    ]
```

i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loopsi want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops
i want to make it like change it like below using javascript loop please please help me about this
when i tried this it is showing infinity loops

```
 {
        "id": "name",
        "model": "name",
        "name": "name",
        "label": "Name",
        "placeholder": "Enter your name",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "text",
        "options": [],
        "objectType":"parent",
        "parentId": ""
      },
    {
        "id": "existingcustomer",
        "name": "ExistingCustomer",
        "label": "Exisiting Customer",
        "placeholder": "",
        "required": "yes",
        "inputType": "radio",
        "objectType":"parent",
        "options": [
          {"label": "Yes", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue": "no","id": "existingcustomer_yes","objectType": "parent",childJson:"here i want to show all child having parent id = this option id"},
          {"label": "No", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue":"yes","id": "existingcustomer_no","objectType": "parent"}
        ],
        "parentId": ""
      }
```

Comment: Adding a childJson in options with id equals parentId is all you want?

Comment: yes sir i only want this please please help me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:
Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "id": "name",
    "model": "name",
    "name": "name",
    "label": "Name",
    "placeholder": "Enter your name",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "objectType":"parent",
    "parentId": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "existingcustomer",
    "name": "ExistingCustomer",
    "label": "Exisiting Customer",
    "placeholder": "",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "radio",
    "objectType":"parent",
    "options": [
      {"label": "Yes", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue": "no","id": "existingcustomer_yes","objectType": "parent"},
      {"label": "No", "name": "eCustomer","optionValue":"yes","id": "existingcustomer_no","objectType": "parent"}
    ],
    "parentId": ""
  },

  {
    "model": "newcustomername",
    "name": "newcustomername",
    "label": "Hello New Customer Please Enter Your Name",
    "placeholder": "Enter You Name",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "objectType": "child",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "existingcustomer_no"
  }
];


let {result, toRemove} = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.options = cur.options.map(itemObj => {
    const childs = arr.filter(arrObj => arrObj.parentId === itemObj.id);
    itemObj.childJson = childs;    
    acc.toRemove = [...acc.toRemove, ...childs.map(item => item.parentId)]
    return itemObj
  })
  acc.result.push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {result:[], toRemove:[]})

result = result.filter(item => !toRemove.includes(item.parentId))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i will try this thanks sir can i have you skype address or facebook or watsapp any thing ??

Comment: You can post your questions here. I am sure your above comment must be against community guidelines.

Comment: ok sir i also want to reduce json when it is setting to option child

Comment: the object setting to child should be removed

Comment: Check my answer. Go to reference links to understand more about the methods used.

Comment: thanks much sir can i get all childs of a parent i means child and there childs too ??

Comment: any answer ?? please reply sir i am wating